# How can i find the commit that created the repository?

Tags: git, command, repository, atlassian-sourcetree

How can i find the history of the repo to find out when it was created?

I have found commands that showcase the log history but it is too large and so was wondering how i can find the first date it was created instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git log --max-parents=0
```

will output (among other info) the date of the repo's older commit, the only one* without parent.

*(* in most cases. But, as ElpieKay reminded us in his comment below, beware that in some more complex repositories, one can have orphan branches. If more than one commit pops out here, compare dates and maybe update your question to add the related output)*

Comment: A repository could have multiple root commits.

Comment: @ElpieKay Yes, this is true. I chose not to mention it to stay on point, and because I guessed that most repositories have only one. But indeed in complex cases orphan branches or unrelated histories can exist. I'll edit, thanks for the comment.